# How can I delete all files in a folder that haven't been accessed in a certain amount of time?

Tags: shell-script, files, cron, date

I'd like to run a nightly cron job that deletes all the files in a folder that haven't been accessed in a week or more. What is the most efficient way to do this in bash?

Comment: `find` can filter based on atime. The "correctness" of atime depends upon configuration (see `noatime`), at the very least.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want the [`find` tool](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).

```
find folder -depth -type f -atime +7 -delete
```

(This will [delete](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Delete-Files.html#Delete-Files) all files ([only regular ones](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Type.html#Type), no pipes, special devices, directories, symbolic links) in the given folder and all subdirectories (recursively) where the last [access time](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html#Age-Ranges) is [longer than](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/find-Expressions.html#find-Expressions) 7 days ago.)

Comment: You might want to add `-type f` in there to ensure it only deletes files, not entire directories.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out `tmpwatch` which can be put into a cron job. No need to roll-your-own with `find`. On RHEL it's in the `tmpwatch` RPM.

Comment: This is definitely the more elegant solution, but I prefer the portability of `find`.